# Liquibase generatechangelog dynamic dates

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to generatechangelog with liquibase. The requirement is to build the liquibase script with dynamic dates. That means that whenever the script runs the dates will be calculated based on the current date. 
Is there a way that liquibase will auto generate the date fields in such a way?

example

```
<insert tableName="account">
        <column name="id" value="1"/>
        <column name="availablebalance" valueNumeric="36239.07"/>
        <column name="currentbalance" valueNumeric="36000.00"/>
        <column name="maturitydate" valueDate="2015-09-30"/>
        <column name="opendate" valueDate="2012-09-30"/>
        <column name="status" value="OPEN"/>
        <column name="title" value="Alpha Deposit"/>
        <column name="version" valueNumeric="0"/>
        <column name="type_id" valueNumeric="20"/>
        <column name="product_id" valueNumeric="2010101121"/>
    </insert>
```

should be something like

```
<insert tableName="account">
        <column name="id" value="1"/>
        <column name="availablebalance" valueNumeric="36239.07"/>
        <column name="currentbalance" valueNumeric="36000.00"/>
        <column name="maturitydate" valueDate="current_date + interval '-5 months'"/>
        <column name="opendate" valueDate="current_date + interval '-5 months'"/>
        <column name="status" value="OPEN"/>
        <column name="title" value="Alpha Deposit"/>
        <column name="version" valueNumeric="0"/>
        <column name="type_id" valueNumeric="20"/>
        <column name="product_id" valueNumeric="2010101121"/>
    </insert>
```

Comment: It could help if you add an example. What date(s) are you refering to? I think the `generateChangeLog` itself does not have such a feature. But to me it's not really clear what kind of dates you would like to be calculated when running `generateChangeLog`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Liquibase does not have any features to do anything like what you are looking for. You would need to write something to post-process the XML to alter the date values.

One possibility would be to scan the XML for `<column>` elements that have `valueDate` attributes and replace the values with un-expanded properties, so that the XML looked like this:

```
<insert tableName="account">
        <column name="id" value="1"/>
        <column name="availablebalance" valueNumeric="36239.07"/>
        <column name="currentbalance" valueNumeric="36000.00"/>
        <column name="maturitydate" valueDate="${todayMinusFiveMonths}"/>
        <column name="opendate" valueDate="${todayMinusFiveMonths}"/>
        <column name="status" value="OPEN"/>
        <column name="title" value="Alpha Deposit"/>
        <column name="version" valueNumeric="0"/>
        <column name="type_id" valueNumeric="20"/>
        <column name="product_id" valueNumeric="2010101121"/>
    </insert>
```

... and then add a `<property>` tag at the top of the file that defines what the actual value should be. That would look something like this:

```
<databaseChangeLog 
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <property name="todayMinusFiveMonths" value="2015-11-10"/>
    ...
    remainder of changelog
    ...
```

Note that even there, you will have to put in a pre-calculated value for the date - I don't think Liquibase has the ability to do any sort of date evaluation at runtime.

Comment: That's what I have been trying to avoid but it figures I will not